# I do not recognize the log4j.xml file in java web

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jax-rs

I am working with jax-rs and jboss 7.1 and it happens that when I put log4j.xml in `src/main/resources` and I start the application apparently does not recognize the configuration in the file in log4j.xml because it does not create the logs file in `D:/logs/learning.log`.

my log4j file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="file" value="D:/logs/learning.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

someone could help me solve it please.

Comment: Does your application contain a log4j.jar? What is it's name?